# Log4net issue on Windows Server 2012

Tags: log4net, windows-server-2012

I have issue with log4net logging on Windows Server 2012.
There is IIS 8 installed. Log4net is configured correctly because on other environments log file is written. Looks like that this issue related to some additional security on 2012 Server.
Has anyone faced with such problems?
I can't find reason why log file is nor written.

One more comment is that IIS 8 doesn't see my web.config file only if I rename it to web.config.txt application is started. It looks very strange for me as I didn't use Server 2012 and IIS 8 earlier.

Comment: has the iis user write access to the log directory?

Comment: I've added full access permission for myapplicationpool user.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to writing log files I tend not to try and write my log files anywhere in the program files directory or anything in any virtual directory just because of the previous battles I've had with security issues.  Currently I'm using something like the following for all my log4net log files:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/<Product Name>/Logs/<Program Name>/<Program Name>.log" />
```

`${ALLUSERSPROFILE}` is the key above.  This directory typically doesn't have the security restrictions as virtual directory and the program files directory.  I've found that I haven't had any trouble since I've been using this path.

This envrionment variable takes you to the `ProgramData` directory in Windows Vista, 7, 8, Server 2008 etc.  I think XP takes you to a different place but still a directory with relaxed permissions.